# combine three tables together in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, inner-join

The question is: "List all official languages with the number of speakers (not the percentage) of that language. For each record in the table, also display the country name and capital. Your results should be first ordered by country name (from A to Z) and then by the number of speakers (from largest to smallest)."

The tables I have are lab2.country, lab2.city, and lab2.country_language.

```
$query5 = "SELECT c.name AS country, c.capital,l.language,c.population,l.percentage, ((c.population * (l.percentage * 0.01)) :: bigint) AS speakers

FROM lab2.country c INNER JOIN lab2.city ci ON (c.country_code = ci.country_code) INNER        JOIN lab2.country_language
ON (c.country_code = l.country_code)
```

^This is where I need to INNER JOIN lab2.country, lab2.city, and lab2.country_language^

```
WHERE l.is_official is true
ORDER BY c.name ASC, speakers DESC";
```

The problem is joining on three tables. First Country with City and then country and country_language. The primary key is country_code.

Comment: Homework? If so, that's OK, it's just nice to explain as much if it's the case.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT c.name AS country, ci.name AS capital, l.language,
((c.population * (l.percentage * 0.01)) :: bigint) AS speakers
```

**FROM lab2.country c INNER JOIN lab2.country_language l 
    ON (c.country_code = l.country_code)
    JOIN lab2.city ci ON (c.country_code = ci.country_code)**

```
WHERE l.is_official is true AND (ci.id = c.capital)
ORDER BY c.name ASC, speakers DESC";
```

The bold is the answer I was looking for. This is INNER JOINING country on country_language and then city onto the already INNER JOINED tables. Thanks!